# MacOS - Using script with launchd - startup, login, logoff, shutdown?

Tags: macos, sh, shutdown, launchd

**MacOS High Sierra**

I want to run this script on startup, login and shutdown, logoff.

The script looks like this and is working successfully from terminal:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /private/my/tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name -specialfolder -exec rm -r {} \;
find /private/my/tmp -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

I have used the Automater to create an .app placed my script in Login Items and this works when logging in, however this does not solve the issue of startup, logoff or shutdown so I do not think that this is the answer.

Reading around, it seems I need to use `launchd`, but I really can't figure out how to do this with my script.

Can anyone please help?

Edit: For using with launchd, how does this look? I am sure to have some mistakes, hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.startup</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/private/myscripts/startup.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>        
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Not saying a launchd agent wouldn't work, but you could do this equally well on logout by making an AppleScript applet instead, which uses the `on quit` handler.

Comment: @ThatsJustCheesy Something like "on quit, tell script /private/myscripts/startup.sh to run, end on quit ?

Comment: You can use `do shell script "/private/myscripts/startup.sh"` to run it from AppleScript. Also, I just tried the quit handler (as I don't use them often) and you'll need to put `continue quit` before `end quit`, or the app won't actually terminate.

Comment: So it's: on quit, do shell script "/private/myscripts/startup.sh", continue quit, end quit ? (Obviously where commas , appear are new lines in the AppleScript). How do I get On Quit to execute? Is it a daemon?

Comment: Yes, that looks right. I would also add: on run, do shell script "/private/myscripts/startup.sh", end run, so that it runs on startup as well. Basically, you can save this script as an Application in Script Editor.app, and then place it in Login Items or use launchd. BTW, your launchd plist looks correct; just point it to your application's executable, in App.app/Contents/MacOS/.

Answer (score 1):

To run the script at both login and logout, you can wrap it in an AppleScript applet.

This AppleScript code will run the script you specify at both startup and termination:

```
to run_script()
    do shell script "/path/to/script.sh"
end run_script

on run
    run_script()
end run

on quit
    run_script()
    continue quit
end quit
```

Save this in Script Editor.app as an "Application", checking the checkbox labelled "Stay open after run handler". Now, the applet will remain open until manually quit or a logout occurs.

The applet *will* appear in the Dock; to disable that, add `LSUIElement` or `LSBackgroundOnly` keys to the applet's Info.plist. Those are well-documented keys that Google can tell you more about.

Now, finally, we need to make it run at login. You can do this either using Login Items or a launchd plist. Your example plist above should work, provided you point it at the applet's executable in, e.g., App.app/Contents/MacOS/.

Comment: Ah, I was just writing a reply, but my new understanding is that it works on login, but not logout. … try writing `display alert "hello from script"` within the `on quit` block to see if it runs. You should have to confirm an alert message before the system logs you out.

Comment: I have managed to get this to run using Login Items after some time. However, it appears that the script is executing at Login rather than Logout/Shutdown/Restart. How can I make it so that it runs at Logout/Shutdown/Restart instead of at Login? I figured the "On Quit" section was handling any Logoff/Shutdown/Restart but it doesn't seem to do anything. The actions of the script appear to take place only upon Login?

Comment: Also, I have tried using the launchd plist but I cannot get it to run. No error messages, just cannot get it to load nor start. I have checked and the permissions seem to be correct, I even set 'Everyone' to Read&Write and still does not work. I think I mentioned above that the top-level folder "private" is hidden. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Also, are you placing your launchd plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents, /Library/LaunchAgents, or somewhere else? If you write a daemon instead of an agent, I believe it'll only run on startup and shutdown. I haven't worked much with daemons however.

Comment: Tried adding the display alert "hello from script" in the on quit block. It seems to run erratically, that is, maybe every 1 in 3 times. It displays on shutdown, sometimes restart, never on logoff.

Comment: launchd plist I am trying to use in ~/Library/LaunchDaemon - it would be good if these even worked for startup/shutdown but it is not working for anything.